# Python pygame.transform.rotate

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I am new to pygame and python itself. 
But right now, i have to make a spinner. It should stop at random times. 
What i was thinking was that i can have random.randint(0, 360). So i can make it stop at random times. But right now, I can only make it rotate 90, or else it moves of the screen.

Any help would be useful.

Thanks

```
import sys, pygame, time

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([600,600])
black = 255,255,0
ball = pygame.image.load("wheel.gif")
temp = pygame.image.load("wheel.gif")


ballrec = ball.get_rect().center

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(black)
    ball = pygame.transform.rotate(ball, 45)
    ballrec = ball.get_rect().center
    screen.blit(ball, ballrec)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that if you keep rotate the rotated object repeatedly, as you're doing in `ball = pygame.transform.rotate(ball, 45)`, the sprite gets distorted and starts to move off screen. I usually keep the original image and switch back to that when I rotate 360 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate), rotating by angles that are not divisible by 90 requires the image being padded. You should be able to just blit the image to always be centered at 128,128 or you can trim off the edges of the image as necessary.